# Finding a Name from a list Where did I go wrong

Tags: java, javascript

```
package stringvars;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Names {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        String Name;
        String li ;

        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            System.out.printf("Please enter your name: ");
            Name= input.next();
            if (Name = li )
                System.out.printf("li has been found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, this is the most famous and most worst type of question in SO actually

Comment: please follow naming conventions for variables, for java it's camel case

Comment: @Lorenzo Ohh God really. The people who downvote are not doing it because they have to show superiority over someone. All are helpful enough to take time out from their schedule and help others. And if the question deserves a downvote it will get it. If there are upvotes so will always be the downvotes.

Comment: So what is the point to downvote this question ?

Comment: @Lorenzo take a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/what-purpose-does-downvoting-questions-serve). _"So what is the point to downvote this question? "_ : the same point with your reason on 18 downvotes cast

Comment: @Lorenzo Read meta.stackoverflow.com for more info on this. The question has multiple issues, which show clear lack of knowledge. So maybe people would have downvoted.

Comment: "which show clear lack of knowledge.." that `precisely`why people come here to ask questions.

Comment: _"Question must show minimal understanding"_

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping a brother out. for all those who disliked my question; I hope you'll be caught in a little trouble while trying to find answers and then you will know what it feels like to be in need.  Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Things you missed

1) Strings must compare with equals method to check they are equal or not.

2) `=`  is assignment operator  not the checking equality.

3) Your `li`  is always `null`, I haven't seen that `li` is assigning to some value.

You might want to check that entered string is li, then get ridoff that  `String li ;`  Simply you can do

```
 if (Name.equals("li")){

 }
```

Or you can do

```
 String li ="li";
```

then

```
  if (Name.equals(li)){

     }
```

Note: Please follow [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). Variable names starts with small.

Comment: Also use proper naming guidelines, `Name` should be `name`

Comment: @NarendraPathai True. I'm on the way to get the link.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `=` which is an assignment operator. You should use `==` for comparison(but be aware, it will compare the references and not the contents for objects, like `String`).

And for specifically for strings, you should use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` method

```
    //initialize li to some value
    String li = "abcd";
    Name= input.next();
    if (Name.equals(li))
        System.out.printf("li has been found");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For String comparision you should use equal() Method of String class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "li" is what you want to search for:-

```
package json;
```

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Names {

```
public void countStringPresence(int numberofUser,String lastName) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String[] Name = new String[numberofUser]; //for Example - 4
     for(int j=0; j<numberofUser; j++){
         System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
         Name[j] = input.next();
    }
      for(String liExist:Name) {
          if(liExist.equals(lastName)) {
              System.out.println("Hurraayyy  !!!! Li has been found");
             break;
          } 
      }
      input.close();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Names nameCheck = new Names();
    nameCheck.countStringPresence(2, "li");
```

}
}

Comment: For every statement that I type in "li" it shows that "li has been found". How can i make it output just one "li has been found" at the end of typing the names.

Comment: You are making you loop run four times. So thats why it is showing it every time.

Comment: In the program I want to allow the user to input a list of last names (e.g., 10 last names) and at the end  check
whether a specific last name (e.g., “Li”) is within the list or not.

Comment: Try the updated code above. I have changed my previous code. you can check

Answer (score 0):

This : `if (Name = li )` shoud be `if(Name.equals(li))`